# Get result from activity called with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android development
I call an intent now  how can i get result from called activity
can any one tell me how to perform this task ? 
i have called intent like.

`Intent I = new Intent (this ,abc.class);
startActivity(i);`

thanks

Comment: What you mean by "how can i get result from called activity" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi  you can get result calling activity

Start activity with  `startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`
add below method in calling activity

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // do your task 

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // do your task 
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `startActivityForResult` and then override `onActivityResult` in your FirstActivity.

In `FirstActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2
```

Override `onActivityResult`

```
 @Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  

                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                            Log.i("Message is",message);
                            // logs Testing

                         }  

     }
```

In `SecondAcivity`

```
Intent intent=new Intent();  
intent.putExtra("MESSAGE","Testing");  
setResult(2,intent);  
finish();//finishing activity
```

Reference to the docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Example:

http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Answer (score 1):

For going to second activity use startActivityForResult in your firstclass

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(FirstClass.this, SecondClass.class);
startActivityForResult(callIntent, 1);
```

then override onActivityResult method in your first class like this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     // Check which request we're responding to
     if (requestCode == 1) {
         // Make sure the request was successful
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            // get values from data
         }
     } }
```

In your second class do this for returning back, if you want to send
something to first class. Store this in your intent.

```
Intent result = new Intent(); setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main Class....

```
static final int CODE_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code
```

....

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(MainClass.this, CallingClassName.class);
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, CODE_REQUEST);
```

..........

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
    }
}
```

In your calling class

```
Intent result = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
finish()
```